# How do I print all of the intermediate steps of MergeSort?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, merge, mergesort

I was assigned a project around two weeks ago in my intro to C++ class that involves working with vectors and sorting algorithms. I have already successfully implemented all of the required algorithms and can verify that they work by printing all of the vectors from both the intermediate steps and the final sorted ones. The only problem I'm having is getting the merge sort to print its intermediate results in the below format:

> [14, 7, 3, 12, 9, 11, 6, 2]
>
> [14, 7, 3, 12] [9, 11, 6, 2]
>
> [14, 7] [3, 12] [9, 11] [6, 2]
>
> [14] [7] [3] [12] [9] [11] [6] [2]
>
> [7, 14] [3, 12] [9, 11] [2, 6]
>
> [3, 7, 12, 14] [2, 6, 9, 11]
>
> [2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12, 14]

where the first and last lines are the original and sorted original vector.

I have already attempted modifying my vector print procedure which takes in the two vectors my merge sort functions creates from half-ing the original array it receives from the callee. it prints the results in a very weird way you will see below. I also gave up on an idea of making a 2d array that could hold everything and be iterated through for each line. It is also relevant to ask where I should make calls to my new and improved print function...?

The following is my procedure for printing the merge sort vectors:

```
/*
    Procedure: printMergeSort
    Purpose:   prints merge sort steps to the console
*/

void printMergeSort(vector <int> left, vector <int> right)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < left.size(); ++i)
    {

        if (i == 0)
            printf("[%d, ", left[i]);
        else if (i < left.size() - 1)
            printf("%d, ", left[i]);
        else
            printf("%d], ", left[i]);

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < right.size(); ++i)
    {

        if (i == 0)
            printf("[%d, ", right[i]);
        else if (i < right.size() - 1)
            printf("%d, ", right[i]);
        else
            printf("%d] \n", right[i]);

    }

}``
```

and my merge and mergesort code:

```
/*
    Procedure: merge
    Purpose:   Helper funcrion for mergeSort...
               Sorts the subarrays and merges them
*/

void merge(vector<int>& leftVector, vector<int>& rightVector, vector<int>& vectortoMerge)
{

    int lefttmostValue = leftVector.size();
    int rightmostValue = rightVector.size();
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    //printMergeSort(leftVector, rightVector);

    while (j < lefttmostValue and k < rightmostValue)
    {

        if (leftVector[j] < rightVector[k])
        {

            vectortoMerge[i] = leftVector[j];
            //printf("%d ", vectortoMerge[i]); 
            ++j;

        }
        else
        {

            vectortoMerge[i] = rightVector[k];

            //printf("%d ", vectortoMerge[i]);
            ++k;

        }

        ++i;

    }
    while (j < lefttmostValue)
    {

        vectortoMerge[i] = leftVector[j];       
        //printf("%d ", vectortoMerge[i]);
        ++j; ++i;

    }

    while (k < rightmostValue) 
    {

        vectortoMerge[i] = rightVector[k];
        //printf("%d ", vectortoMerge[i]);
        ++k; ++i;

    }

}

/*
    procedure: mergeSort
    Purpose:   Main function for the merge sort algorithm....
               Splits the vector into 2 and makes a call the merge() function
*/

void mergeSort(vector<int>& vectortoSort)
{
    if (vectortoSort.size() <= 1) return;

    int middleElement = vectortoSort.size() / 2;
    vector<int> leftVector;
    vector<int> rightVector;

    for (int j = 0; j < middleElement; ++j)
        leftVector.push_back(vectortoSort[j]);
    for (int j = 0; j < (vectortoSort.size()) - middleElement; ++j)
        rightVector.push_back(vectortoSort[middleElement + j]);

    printMergeSort(leftVector, rightVector);
    printf(", ");
    mergeSort(leftVector);
    mergeSort(rightVector);
    merge(leftVector, rightVector, vectortoSort);


}
```

The expected output is stated above but when inputting those values, I get the following:

> [14, 7, 3, 12], [9, 11, 6, 2][14, 7], [3, 12][14, [7, [3, [12, [9, 11], [6, 2][9, [11, [6, [2,

Is there a better approach out there in order to solve this problem? I would really appreciate a helping hand, as all of my colleagues and friends are stumped on this one!

Thank you!!!

Comment: Who assigned this, exactly? It seems pretty evil....

Comment: the output is weird because printMergeSort doesn't handle a one element array correctly.

Comment: i would go with the idea of storing the intermediate results.  perhaps an array of strings indexed by recursion level, where you append to the string (rather than print) based on the level.  the printing would only be done at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the index at printing. When array sizes are small, the else of your code are not being reached (sorry for my english): try something like this

```
printf("[");
for (int i = 0; i < left.size(); ++i)
{
    if (i != 0)
        printf(", ");
    printf("%d", left[i]);
}
printf("], [");

for (int i = 0; i < right.size(); ++i)
{
    if (i != 0)
        printf(", ");
    printf("%d", right[i]);
}
printf("]\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree to Karl Knechtel's answer. But there's a way out ( the hard way out) : count every level of recursive depth and push the corresponding vector along side the level index to a container; print the container level-wise. Here's a snippet ( not optimized):

```
void print(const vector<int>& vec) {
    printf("[");
    for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++) {
        (it == vec.end() - 1) ? printf("%d", *it) : printf("%d, ", *it);
    }
    printf("]");
}

vector<pair<int, vector<int>>> vecs;
static int MaxDepth = 0;

void mergeSort(vector<int>& vectortoSort, int level = 0)
{
    if (level > MaxDepth) MaxDepth = level + 1;
    if (vectortoSort.size() <= 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    int middleElement = vectortoSort.size() / 2;
    vector<int> leftVector;
    vector<int> rightVector;

    for (int j = 0; j < middleElement; ++j)
        leftVector.push_back(vectortoSort[j]);
    for (int j = 0; j < (vectortoSort.size()) - middleElement; ++j)
        rightVector.push_back(vectortoSort[middleElement + j]);

    vecs.push_back(make_pair(level, leftVector));  mergeSort(leftVector, level + 1);
    vecs.push_back(make_pair(level, rightVector)); mergeSort(rightVector, level + 1);

    merge(leftVector, rightVector, vectortoSort);
    vecs.push_back(make_pair(MaxDepth +1 - level, vectortoSort));
}

void main()
{
    vector<int> vec{ 14, 7, 3, 12, 9, 11, 6, 2 };
    vecs.push_back(make_pair(-1, vec));
    mergeSort(vec); 
    for (int i = -1; i < MaxDepth + 2; i++) {
        for (const auto& e : vecs) {
            if (e.first == i)
            {
                print(e.second);
                cout << "  ";
            }
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Here's a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works awesomely for printing. How would make it work for outputting to a file? check the answer below to see what I'm getting.

Comment: What is the best way to convert the int to char before printing? Here's an example for clarification: initial vector holds 65, 66, 67  when printing it I would like it to output A, B, C (optionally just use char from the beginning)

Answer (score 0):

The first call produces the desired `[14, 7, 3, 12], [9, 11, 6, 2]` line correctly; then the first recursive call is applied to `[14, 7, 3, 12]` and **completely** sorts that half (recursively) before **anything** is done with the second half. Thus there is no way to produce the desired `[14, 7] [3, 12] [9, 11] [6, 2]` line because the recursion will keep processing the `[14, 7] [3, 12]` chunks before the `[9, 11] [6, 2]` can print.

To fix this you would need to convert away from recursion completely, into a breadth-first traversal.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome answers guys!!

I also need to output my vector to a file for each algorithm.
Here's what I'm getting using @seccpur 's print method:

> [, 14, 7, 312] [, 9, 11, 62]
>
> [, 147] [, 312] [, 911] [, 62]
>
> [14] [7] [3] [12] [9] [11] [6] [2]
>
> [, 714] [, 312] [, 911] [, 26]
>
> [, 3, 7, 1214] [, 2, 6, 911]
>
> [, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 11, 1214]

How do I make @seccpur 's print code work for my ofstream object?